# How to find the particular solution to this inhomogeneous ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having issues solving this ODE

$$2y''-4y'+4y=1 $$

Solution to $ 2y''-4y'+4y=0 $ is $y(x)= (C_1+C_2x)e^{2x} $

But how do I get the approach to the particular solution ?
I tried to find about different methods, but I couldn't find anything that worked for this right ..any help very appreciated!

Comment: **Hint:** Choose $$y_p(x) = a$$ Take derivates, substitute back in and solve for $a$.

Comment: I would check your question - is it $2y''$ as stated, in which case your. solution doesn't work (you need to drop the $2$).  And note that the derivative of a constant is zero.

Comment: It's easy to see that $y=1/4$ is a particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Ansatz* $y_p = A,$ where $A$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

$$2y''-4y'+4y=1$$
The characteristic polynomial is:
$$2r^2-4r+4=0$$
$$r^2-2r+2=0$$
$$\Delta =4-4*2=-4 \implies r=1 \pm i$$
The solution to the homogeneous DE is
$$y=e^t(c_1 \cos t +c_2 \sin t)$$
For the particular solution choose $y_p=A$

Or maybe the original DE is ?
$$y''-4y'+4y=1$$